# Communicate between android application and server considering there is no internet connection on android device?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application which requires a server. One component of the application is used by people who do not have internet connection. But still I want to interact with the server. Is there anyway to send messages to server without internet connection? Can we send SMS to server and if yes how? I have read SMS gateway on the net but I failed to understand it.

Comment: You could cache the information and send it when connection is available (open wifi).. is this enough for your needs?

Comment: @user3368363, how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are no Android devices without internet connection, they need one at least to connect to Google Play to download your application.

You might have devices that have no connection for some time, then sending a SMS is theoretically possible but will cost money to the user so he is likely to disapprove this approach.

To receive the SMSs sent by devices, look for a "sms receive gateway", you will find companies that offer you an API to send and receive SMSs from your server. If you don't expect a huge traffic, you can have a phone at your home with a Wifi connection that receives the SMS and sends them back to you server.

Comment: Let me tell you specifically. Project has 3 components - (1)server maintains DB and acts an communication channel between operator android app and admin android app (2)admin android app (these people are managers and they use internet- so no problem here to connect ot server),(3) operator android app (these are labours in a factory who do not know and do not use internet connection - internet feature is available on android but these people very low salaried people and do not have any idea about internet) So I have a problem with 3rd component. How can i send data from 3rd component to server?

Comment: The premise of this answer - that there are no devices without Internet connections - is simply untrue.  And "android" in no way implies that Google Play, or *any* online distribution system, is being used.

Comment: You'll need a network coverage in the factory (assuming you want to connect with them in the factory), a Wifi network can be deployed there and a simple firewall could allow only your server to be reached and not the general internet (or the server can even be in the factory). You can also reach a mobile operator about a VPN deployment that would allow the devices to connect through GPRS, EDGE or 3G to your server, that should be cheaper than a SIM card and a contract for each device.

Comment: Chris Stratton: Yes, theoretically such devices exists, but practically there are none or almost none of them. If it's not Google Play it's another provided (Amazon ?).

Answer (score 1):

Services like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms/api) and [Plivo](https://plivo.com/) will forward SMS messages to your server.  However, I don't know of any free services for this (and I think Twilio may not be available in certain geographies).

This approach will allow phone users to communicate with your server using SMS (via one of these providers).  While your phone user will not need to be connected to the internet (but they will need to have cell service that allows them to send an SMS), your server must be connected to the internet so that it can receive messages from the provider (Twilio or Plivo, for example).

Comment: Twilio requires internet connection? I checked their website and it looks like it needs internet

Comment: It is my understanding that the you are asking about situations where the phone user is not connected to the internet, but has cell service and can text, right?  Twilio (and other SMS services) would allow the phone user to send an SMS to a phone number and/or SMS short code.  Twilio will then send the SMS to your server (if you wish) and this means that your server will need to be connected to the internet, but the phone user will not need to be connected to the internet.  You can think of it as Twilio forwarding the SMS to your server.  (And Twilio can also allow your server to send SMS.)

Comment: Its really great to know. Really thanks for this. Could you pls tell me how twilio forward the message to server? any twilio APIs i need to use?

Comment: [The Twilio link in my answer](https://www.twilio.com/sms/api) is to the Twilio API.  You can check out the Plivo site to get their API, and I'd recommend considering other providers.  I'm familiar with Twilio but have not used any of the others so I'm not recommending one over another.  And @NicolasDefranoux's solution about using your home phone is a great suggestion for prototyping.